# Weights explosion with a simple demo

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I am trying a very simple model :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

X = [-1,0,1,2 ,3,4,5,7,8]
y = [-3,-1,1,3,5,7,9,13,15]

# create model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['acc'])

history=model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, batch_size=8, verbose=0)

pred = model.predict([10])
print("The prediction for 10 is {}".format(pred[0][0]))
```

This works fine until here. The issue starts when I tried to train on a bigger data :

```
X1 = [i for i in range(-25,25)]
y1 = [ ((2*i)-1) for i in X1]
```

Then the accuracy start getting nan.

Can anyone explain the reason of the issue ? and if there is a workaround.

Comment: Accuracy is not a suitable metric for regression, as it expects binary or categorical labels. Use MSE or RMSE instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the combination of the size of the inputs, your loss function, the optimizer and learning rate means the weights are being updated in very large increments. So it can't converge when you train the model with the larger inputs. If you normalize your inputs and/or decrease the learning rate (which defaults to 0.01 in Keras) you should find the model converges. Other ways to fix this could be using the mean_absolute_error loss function instead of mean_squared_error, as this will give smaller errors (using unnormalized inputs) or another optimizer (using the Adam optimizer worked ok for me on your demo model).